# NSTimer does not fire in next date time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I need to fire timer on the basis of the time selected in the date picker.
Now if the selected time is greater than my current time then the `NSTimeInterval` returns positive value and the timer fired correctly.

My problem is when I select the time which is less than the current time then the `NSTimeInterval` returns negative value.

So Now what I does is :- add seconds so that it gets fired next day by 24*60*60.

The seconds value is coming correct because when I test this by changing the time into date it returns the next date with the selected time.

I use these seconds value in setting my timer.

Here is my code :

```
NSTimeInterval value=[[self.pickerView date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];

        value=value+24*60*60;
        NSLog(@"value =%f",value);


        NSDate *d1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:value];
        NSLog(@"%@",d1);
        NSDateFormatter *format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
        NSString *str=[format stringFromDate:d1];
        NSLog(@"str=%@",str);
        [format release];
        NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d1
                                              interval: 1
                                                target: app
                                              selector:@selector(fireWakeUpTimerMethod:)
                                              userInfo:dict repeats:NO];
      //  app.WakeUPTimer=t;
        NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runner addTimer:t forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [t release];
```

But the timer is not getting fired.

I tested it like this:- Suppose my device current time is 15 june 11:00 am then I select the 10:00 am time in picker view , since 10:00 am is less than 11:00 am then the time interval returns negative value so in this case I do value=value+(24*60*60); and set my timer with this value .Then I open the settings app and change my device date and time to 16 june 9:58 am and close settings app and open my app.But the method did not fire at 10:00 am.Please tell us if this is the correct way of testing this scenario.or I am doing some mistake in testing instead of coding.

Please help me as I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your implementation of fireWakeUpTimerMethod: ? Is the date in NSLog correct?

Comment: Please describe how you tested it.

Comment: @tia I tested it like this:- Suppose my device current time is 15 june 11:00 am  then I select the 10:00 am time in picker view , since 10:00 am is less than 11:00 am then the time interval returns negative value so in this case I do value=value+(24*60*60); and set my timer with this value .Then I open the settings app and change my device date and time to 16 june 9:58 am and close settings app and open my app.But the method did not fire at 10:00 am.Please tell us if this is the correct way of testing this scenario.Please help.

Comment: @Pfitz I am playing a song in this method.But the problem is that the method is not getting called.

Comment: @tia please look at it and let me know if the mistake is in testing.I am a newbie to iphone programming.

Comment: Save date in userdefault. when application goes background it will come to forground then foregroundmethod of appDelegate will be fired so add your code there with date in nsuserdefault

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting **value** correct:

```
 value=value+(24*60*60);
```

Also check **target of NSTimer** and its **selector**

Comment: I have added parenthesis in value to calculate correct value as u missed calulated value

Comment: The problem is not the value ,only the timer is not getting fired.

Comment: what is app in target u have used?

Comment: object of appDelegate because the method that should be fired is in appDelegate.